# Fourier transform of a function of bounded variation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I know if $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$ is two times continuously differentiable, then we must have that the Fourier transform is integrable. Is there any more relaxed condition than this? For example if $f$ is continuously differentiable and $f^\prime $ is of bounded variation, will it imply that $f^\prime$ is integrable. Assume that all the functions are compactly supported.

Comment: No, for example the FT of  step function has decay $1/x$. (I assume that a hat is missing and you're asking if a BV function has integrable FT.)

Comment: When f is of bounded variation the Fourier sine transform F^s(f) and the Fourier cosine transform F^c(f) -which form the Fourier transform of a function f := F^f(f)= F^c(f) -i F^s(f) have different behavior. Respectively, F^s(f) is not (HK-)integrable while F^c(f) is.

Answer (score 1):

If $f'$ is of bounded variation, then $\hat{f}$ will be integrable. To see this, note that by your assumptions, $f''$ (in the sense of tempered distributions) is a finite complex-valued measure, so that $\widehat{f''}$ is bounded, meaning that $|\hat{f}(\xi)|\lesssim 1/(1+|\xi|^2)$.